# change node field value without node->save or without causing hook_entity_presave infinite loop

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

Have `CONTENT_TYPE_NAME` with `field_counter` that the user can set when editing a node.  If a user edits and updates that field I want all other nodes that have this field set (to an equal or higher value) to increment their values by 1.  I am overriding `hook_entity_presave` for this purpose.

As you can see in the following code I am getting all nodes of the same content type using `entityQuery` exluding the node that was about to be saved.  For all the nodes found I am getting the entity and incrementing the field value by 1 and setting the field value and saving the node.

```
    function MY_MODULE_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity){ 
      if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {
        $changed_field = array(
            "field_counter",
        );
        $nid = $entity->id();
        foreach($changed_field as $field ){
          $value = $entity->{$field}->value;
          if(isset($value) && $value !=""){
            MY_MODULE_change_field_value($field,$value,$nid);
            //...
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function MY_MODULE_change_field_value($field,$value,$xeid){  
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition('type', 'CONTENT_TYPE_NAME')
        ->condition('nid', $xeid,"<>")
        ->condition($field,$value,">=");

      $nids = $query->execute();

      foreach ($nids as $nid) {
        $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
        //or
        //$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node")->load($nid);
         
        $old_value = $node->{$field}->value;
        $old_value++;
        $node->{$field}->value = $old_value;
        
        $node->save();    
      }
    }
```

This code works with but has a problem. All nodes updated programmatically will call entity_presave again and cause an infinite loop.

I did not find a way to update field value without calling `node->save()` if there is a way please let me know (I know there was a way in drupal 7 `field_attach_update` which is deprecated as of 8.0.x I think)

Is there a way to call `node->save()` which does not call `hook_entity_presave` ?

or alternativelly what checks can I do in the `hook_entity_presave` to know if the field was just updated programmatically and not from user edit ?

Comment: Check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211083/update-a-field-without-changing-the-node

Comment: This post does not answer my question really. My problem is not saving the `presaved` node without node->save but other nodes that I get on the fly ... please read the question thoroughly.

Comment: Then don't use `Node::load()` and instead query the field_counter DB table directly.

Comment: Sounds good !! any pointer will be helpful ...

Comment: There is no supported API to do this, interacting with the tables directly might break in future versions

Comment: @Berdir he could use the replacements of [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!database.inc/function/db_select/8.2.x) and [db_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_update/8.0.x), `Connection::select` and `Connection::update`

Comment: @NoSssweat that does not make it a supported API. Almost all tables are abstracted by services/API's that should be used instead. They are meant to be replaceable, another site might use MongoDB or so. Somewhat unlikely for custom code for a custom site but it's still possible that core will make a change that will break it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I have found a simple solution

add revision message with UNIQUE string before saving the node

```
    //...
    $node->setNewRevision(TRUE);
    $node->revision_log->value = "AUTOMATED-UPDATE ". $field." incremented to ".$old_value ;
    $node->save();
```

check on the `hook_entity_presave` that the revision was not AUTOMATED by checking in the log for our UNIQUE string

```
    if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {
        $log = $entity->revision_log->value;
        if( substr( $log, 0, 16 ) === "AUTOMATED-UPDATE" )
            return;
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, any kind of flag that prevents a recursion should work, can be on the node, or you could also set a static/global variable.

Comment: I figured this way I have the added benefit that anyone looking at the revision log later on will know why/how this UPDATE was done

Comment: Sure that makes sense, but make sure you actually save it as a new revision then with setNewRevision(TRUE), otherwise you'll replace the existing revision log message.